# JSF h:commandlink not working after updating version

Tags: java, jsp, jsf-2

I am working on migrating an application from websphere to tomcat which was been for the most part completely successful. The previous application was running on Java EE 5 and I updated it to Java 7. In the process I updated JSTL to 1.2, myfaces to 2.0, and a few other things. This is my current lib of jars:

[Library of Jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUgLs.png)

Everything about the application works except for the h:commandlink. I believe this has to do with updating the jars and java version. I have access to all other pages it's just the nav buttons do not work. This is the jsp for them:

```
<%-- tpl:metadata --%>
<%-- jsf:pagecode language="java" location="/src/pagecode/menu/Main.java" --%><%-- /jsf:pagecode --%>
<%-- /tpl:metadata --%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.ibm.com/jsf/html_extended" prefix="hx"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
href="../theme/menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../theme/stylesheet.css"
title="Style">
<hx:viewFragment id="viewFragmentMain"><hx:scriptCollector id="scriptCollector1">

    <% String Page = (session.getAttribute("mainPage") == null) ? "1" : (String)session.getAttribute("mainPage"); %>

    <h:form id="formMenu" styleClass="form">
        <ul id="tabmenu">
            <li<%= (Page.compareTo("1") == 0) ? " class=active" : ""%>><h:commandLink id="link1" action="#{pc_Main.doLink1Action}"><h:outputText id="textMenu1" styleClass="outputText" value="Page 1"></h:outputText></h:commandLink></li>
            <li<%= (Page.compareTo("2") == 0) ? " class=active" : ""%>><h:commandLink id="link2" action="#{pc_Main.doLink2Action}"><h:outputText id="textMenu2" styleClass="outputText" value="Page 2"></h:outputText></h:commandLink></li>
            <li<%= (Page.compareTo("3") == 0) ? " class=active" : ""%>><h:commandLink id="link3" action="#{pc_Main.doLink3Action}"><h:outputText id="textMenu3" styleClass="outputText" value="Page 3"></h:outputText></h:commandLink></li>
            <li<%= (Page.compareTo("5") == 0) ? " class=active" : ""%>><h:commandLink id="link5" action="#{pc_Main.doLink5Action}"><h:outputText id="textMenu5" styleClass="outputText" value="Page 5"></h:outputText></h:commandLink></li>
            <% if (request.isUserInRole("giftAdmin") | request.isUserInRole("giftAdminBackup") | request.isUserInRole("merchAdmin") | request.isUserInRole("merchAdminBackup")){ %>
            <li <%= (Page.compareTo("4") == 0) ? " class=active" : ""%>><h:commandLink
                id="link4" action="#{pc_Main.doLink4Action}">
                <h:outputText id="textMenu4" styleClass="outputText"
                    value="Page 4"></h:outputText>
            </h:commandLink></li>
            <li><a href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/forms/Help.pdf" target="_blank">Help</a></li>
            <% } %>
        </ul>
    </h:form>
</hx:scriptCollector>
```

When a link is clicked it is suppose to call the corresponding method found in this class. However, it never actually makes it into this class. It's suppose to make a call in the index then based on the navigation rule it returns the proper view, but it never makes it into the correct method.

```
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandLink;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.accounting.credit.ControlBean;
import com.accounting.credit.CreditAction;
import com.accounting.credit.CreditRequest;

import jxl.common.Logger;
import pagecode.PageCodeBase;

public class Main extends PageCodeBase {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    protected HtmlCommandLink link2;
    protected HtmlOutputText textMenu1;
    protected HtmlForm formMenu;
    protected HtmlCommandLink link3;
    protected HtmlCommandLink link4;
    protected HtmlCommandLink link1;
    protected HtmlOutputText textMenu2;
    protected HtmlOutputText textMenu3;
    protected HtmlOutputText textMenu4;
    protected CreditAction action;
    protected CreditRequest req;
    protected ControlBean control;
    protected HtmlOutputText textMenu5;
    protected HtmlCommandLink link5;

    protected HtmlCommandLink getLink2() {
        if (link2 == null) {
            link2 = (HtmlCommandLink) findComponentInRoot("link2");
        }
        return link2;
    }

    protected HtmlOutputText getTextMenu1() {
        if (textMenu1 == null) {
            textMenu1 = (HtmlOutputText) findComponentInRoot("textMenu1");
        }
        return textMenu1;
    }

    protected HtmlForm getFormMenu() {
        if (formMenu == null) {
            formMenu = (HtmlForm) findComponentInRoot("formMenu");
        }
        return formMenu;
    }

    protected HtmlCommandLink getLink3() {
        if (link3 == null) {
            link3 = (HtmlCommandLink) findComponentInRoot("link3");
        }
        return link3;
    }

    protected HtmlCommandLink getLink4() {
        if (link4 == null) {
            link4 = (HtmlCommandLink) findComponentInRoot("link4");
        }
        return link4;
    }

    protected HtmlCommandLink getLink1() {
        if (link1 == null) {
            link1 = (HtmlCommandLink) findComponentInRoot("link1");
        }
        return link1;
    }

    public String doLink1Action() {
        // Type Java code that runs when the component is clicked
        LOG.info("In doLink1Action"); 
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession)getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("edit", "False");
        getReq().clear();
        getAction().clear();
        return "page1";
    }

    public String doLink2Action() {
        // Type Java code that runs when the component is clicked
        LOG.info("In doLink2Action");
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession)getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("edit", "False");
        getReq().clear();
        getAction().clear();
        return "page2";
    }

    public String doLink3Action() {
        // Type Java code that runs when the component is clicked
        LOG.info("In doLink3Action");
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession)getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("edit", "False");
        getReq().clear();
        getAction().clear();
        return "pag3";
    }

    public String doLink4Action() {
        // Type Java code that runs when the component is clicked
        LOG.info("In doLink4Action");
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession)getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("edit", "False");
        getReq().clear();
        getAction().clear();
        return "page4";
    }

    protected HtmlOutputText getTextMenu2() {
        if (textMenu2 == null) {
            textMenu2 = (HtmlOutputText) findComponentInRoot("textMenu2");
        }
        return textMenu2;
    }

    protected HtmlOutputText getTextMenu3() {
        if (textMenu3 == null) {
            textMenu3 = (HtmlOutputText) findComponentInRoot("textMenu3");
        }
        return textMenu3;
    }

    protected HtmlOutputText getTextMenu4() {
        if (textMenu4 == null) {
            textMenu4 = (HtmlOutputText) findComponentInRoot("textMenu4");
        }
        return textMenu4;
    }

    /** 
     * @managed-bean true
     */
    protected CreditAction getAction() {
        if (action == null) {
            action = (CreditAction) getFacesContext().getApplication()
                .createValueBinding("#{action}")
                .getValue(getFacesContext());
        }
        return action;
    }

    /** 
     * @managed-bean true
     */
    protected void setAction(CreditAction action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    /** 
     * @managed-bean true
     */
    protected CreditRequest getReq() {
        if (req == null) {
            req = (CreditRequest) getFacesContext().getApplication()
                .createValueBinding("#{req}").getValue(getFacesContext());
        }
        return req;
    }

    /** 
     * @managed-bean true
     */
    protected void setReq(CreditRequest req) {
        this.req = req;
    }

    /** 
     * @managed-bean true
     */
    protected ControlBean getControl() {
        if (control == null) {
            control = (ControlBean) getFacesContext().getApplication()
                .createValueBinding("#{control}").getValue(
                        getFacesContext());
        }
        return control;
    }

    /** 
     * @managed-bean true
     */
    protected void setControl(ControlBean control) {
        this.control = control;
    }

    protected HtmlOutputText getTextMenu5() {
        if (textMenu5 == null) {
            textMenu5 = (HtmlOutputText) findComponentInRoot("textMenu5");
        }
        return textMenu5;
    }

    protected HtmlCommandLink getLink5() {
        if (link5 == null) {
            link5 = (HtmlCommandLink) findComponentInRoot("link5");
        }
        return link5;
    }

    public String doLink5Action() {
        // Type Java code that runs when the component is clicked
        return "page5";
    }

}
```

The onclick is different from the one that was working previous, which makes me believe it has to do with the version but I haven't found anything relating to why the onclick would change.

The onclick previous was:

```
<a id="viewFragmentMain:formMenu:link2" href="#" onclick="document.forms['viewFragmentMain:formMenu']['__LINK_TARGET__'].disabled=false;document.forms['viewFragmentMain:formMenu']['__LINK_TARGET__'].value='viewFragmentMain:formMenu:link2'; document.forms['viewFragmentMain:formMenu'].submit();document.forms['viewFragmentMain:formMenu']['__LINK_TARGET__'].disabled=true; return false;"><span id="viewFragmentMain:formMenu:textMenu2" class="outputText">My Requests</span></a>
```

The onclick for the new one is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return myfaces.oam.submitForm('viewFragmentMain:formMenu','viewFragmentMain:formMenu:link2');" id="viewFragmentMain:formMenu:link2"><span id="viewFragmentMain:formMenu:textMenu2" class="outputText">My Requests</span></a>
```

Simply, I guess I'm asking is how can I make the new link look like the old one with the update versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the issue related to using the old Websphere jars that were still "in use". I had the tag library above, of IBM faces using the prefix hx. This only works on Websphere server. So in the process of removing them I had to redo the tags that were implemented which most had easy equivalents. The other issue that came up, on the backend of it, we implemented for IBM Faces so I am currently in the process of rewriting to incorporate the actually used tags. I also had to change the web.xml which was still set up to include IMB context-params, so I removed them.

As you can see here, I removed the hx tag library which allowed the links to work and there are no problems. I also had to remove all mention of IBM instnaces and sources from the web.xml file.

```
<%-- tpl:metadata --%>
<%-- jsf:pagecode language="java" location="/src/pagecode/menu/Main.java" --%><%-- /jsf:pagecode --%>
<%-- /tpl:metadata --%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="theme/menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme/stylesheet.css" title="Style">

    <% String Page = (session.getAttribute("mainPage") == null) ? "1" : (String)session.getAttribute("mainPage"); %>

    <h:form id="formMenu" styleClass="form">
        <ul id="tabmenu">
            <li<%= (Page.compareTo("1") == 0) ? " class=active" : ""%>><h:commandLink id="link1" action="#{pc_Main.doLink1Action}"><h:outputText id="textMenu1" styleClass="outputText" value="Credit/Gift Card Request"></h:outputText></h:commandLink></li>
            <li<%= (Page.compareTo("2") == 0) ? " class=active" : ""%>><h:commandLink id="link2" action="#{pc_Main.doLink2Action}"><h:outputText id="textMenu2" styleClass="outputText" value="My Requests"></h:outputText></h:commandLink></li>
            <li<%= (Page.compareTo("3") == 0) ? " class=active" : ""%>><h:commandLink id="link3" action="#{pc_Main.doLink3Action}"><h:outputText id="textMenu3" styleClass="outputText" value="My ToDo's"></h:outputText></h:commandLink></li>
            <li<%= (Page.compareTo("5") == 0) ? " class=active" : ""%>><h:commandLink id="link5" action="#{pc_Main.doLink5Action}"><h:outputText id="textMenu5" styleClass="outputText" value="Search"></h:outputText></h:commandLink></li>
            <% if (request.isUserInRole("giftAdmin") | request.isUserInRole("giftAdminBackup") | request.isUserInRole("merchAdmin") | request.isUserInRole("merchAdminBackup")){ %>
            <li <%= (Page.compareTo("4") == 0) ? " class=active" : ""%>><h:commandLink
                id="link4" action="#{pc_Main.doLink4Action}">
                <h:outputText id="textMenu4" styleClass="outputText"
                    value="Accounting"></h:outputText>
            </h:commandLink></li>
            <li><a href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/forms/Help.pdf" target="_blank">Help</a></li>
            <% } %>
        </ul>
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of WebSphere?
Usually you must not bundle the JSF implementation jars in your app except if you explicitily wnat to override the one bundled in WAS. If so, check the doc [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tweb_jsf22.html)

Comment: It was 6.1 but now it is running on Tomcat 7